# Type Inference when using Vue + Typescript and Vue Components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vetur

I have a .vue component that is being imported into another .vue component/SFC or whatever you wanna call it. With Stencil/React you can create your components with JSX/TSX and when that particular component is export, you will get a definition file that will give you the information necessary for typescript to infer the props used by certain component.

```
App.vue file
<template>
   <Child :name="Vue">
<template/>
```

```
Child.vue file

<template>
   <div>
      {{ name }}
   </div>
<template/>
```

I'm not writing the rest of the code because that's self explanatory( I hope :))

What I want is that when I try to do:

```
<Child :name="2">
```

it should throw a compile error/ IDE would error, or whatever. I don't want to rely on Vue runtime telling me that I inserted a number instead of a string there. 
I also don't want to write a rely on writing .json files for Vetur for example to read and autocomplete based on that.

With these constraints, the current state of Vue and tooling, is that possible ?
Maybe only changing to Vue + TSX ?
Also, if you know any solid starters for TSX's + Vue, that would be fantastic.

Thankks !